# Ionic Cordova Angular add text on top of gif

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Say I have a gif file locally in the project, is there any existing plugins/libraries can place a layer of text on the gif (i.e. draw on the gif) ,generate and download the new gif file?

If there's not, can someone suggest a rough idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: use http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: isn't it only for svg to canvas and vice versa?